# Autocompletetextview with custom adapter and filter

Tags: android

I am trying to set a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my `AutoCompleteTextView` like this

```
public class AutoCompleteContactArrayAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<Map<String, String>> implements Filterable {
private Context mContext;
private List<Map<String, String>> mContactList;

public AutoCompleteContactArrayAdapter(Context context,
        List<Map<String, String>> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.auto_contact_list, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mContactList = objects;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_contact_list, parent,
            false);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontName);
    TextView phoneView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontNo);
    TextView typeView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontType);
    Map<String, String> contactMap = mContactList.get(position);

    nameView.setText(contactMap.get("name"));
    phoneView.setText(contactMap.get("phone"));
    typeView.setText(contactMap.get("type"));

    return rowView;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            result.add("test");
            result.add("another");
            result.add("last");
            FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
            r.values = result;
            r.count = result.size();
            return r;
        }
    };
}
}
```

In debug the application is entering the `filter` methods both `publishResults()` and `performFiltering()` but the result set that is being displayed is not my test `array` [test,another,last] instead it just shows all the results ignoring my filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay i think i figure out what Luksprog was saying this code works now they key is this

```
mContactList = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) results.values;
```

in

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return mContactList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_contact_list, parent,
            false);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontName);
    TextView phoneView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontNo);
    TextView typeView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ccontType);
    Map<String, String> contactMap = mContactList.get(position);

    nameView.setText(contactMap.get("name"));
    phoneView.setText(contactMap.get("phone"));
    typeView.setText(contactMap.get("type"));

    return rowView;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count > 0) {
                mContactList = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            myMap.put("name", "key");
            result.add(myMap);
            HashMap<String,String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            myMap2.put("name", "is");
            result.add(myMap2);
            HashMap<String,String> myMap3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
            myMap3.put("name", "another");
            result.add(myMap3);
            FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
            r.values = result;
            r.count = result.size();
            return r;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Here is the current implementation of my code:

The xml

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/searchAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/abs__textfield_search_default_holo_light"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abs__ic_search_api_holo_light"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/abs__ic_clear_holo_light"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" >
```

The adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> fullList;
    private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        fullList = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fullList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return fullList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }


    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        private Object lock;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(mOriginalValues);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<String> values = mOriginalValues;
                int count = values.size();

                ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String item = values.get(i);
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(item);
                    }

                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if(results.values!=null){
        fullList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        }else{
            fullList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in code initialize like this...

```
       ArrayList<String> searchArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
//initilaze this array with your data
        AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, android.R.id.text1, searchArrayList);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.searchAutoComplete);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Done :)

Comment: Hi, I understand almost all besides `mOriginalValues`. I don't understand for what we need it. Can you explain me, please?

Comment: This is not an optimized code you can change is according to your need :)

Comment: Yeah, sooper good SOLUTION  its works 100% :) Thanx a lot Ali Imran

Comment: Why you have used `synchronized (lock)` only for clearing the list and not for assigning new values? @AliImran

Answer (score 2):

Autocompletetextview uses Adapter to show auto complete suggestion drop down.

Adapater should be filterable and should give view populating data for each item from data list. Autocompletetextview uses filter defined in the adapter to get results and show them.

So, if you need to create custom adapter, you need to provide implementation for getView and provide a filter class.

Complete working example of 
autocompletetextview custom layout and custom adapter

http://www.zoftino.com/android-autocompletetextview-custom-layout-and-adapter

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who interested in Kotlin version you may find below.

```
val ac = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.searchAutoComplete)
var dataList = listOf("argument", "aid", "appear", "air", "advertise", "appendix", "apathy", "absence", "analysis",
    "bind", "bathroom", "broadcast", "bomb", "build", "bark", "beef", "brain", "bend",
    "conviction", "coincide", "castle", "cafe", "chemistry", "clean", "closed", "composer", "care", "crude")
ac.setAdapter(object : ArrayAdapter<String>(
    context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, android.R.id.text1, dataList,
), Filterable {
    private var oriValue = dataList.toList()
    override fun getCount() = dataList.size
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = dataList[position]
    override fun getFilter() = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(prefix: CharSequence?) =
            FilterResults().apply {
                mutableListOf<String>().apply {
                    if (prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty()) addAll(oriValue)
                    else oriValue.map {
                        if (it.contains(prefix.toString(), true)) // ignore case
                        // if (it.contains(prefix.toString())) // match case
                        // if (it.startsWith(prefix.toString(), true)) // start with
                            add(it)
                    }
                    values = this
                    count = this.size
                }
            }
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            dataList = results?.values as List<String>? ?: listOf()
            if (results?.count ?: -1 > 0) notifyDataSetChanged() 
            else notifyDataSetInvalidated()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanna add the data in

`String[] arr=new String[100];`

then its wrong.
You can do the same work as in form of ArrayList but remember you will never put here a Getter/Setter class. Just simply declare it. See this example.

Declare in main partition:

```
   ArrayList<String>arr=new ArrayList<>();
```

and then initilize it in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                String imei = jsonObject1.getString("imei");
                String name = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                String my_pic = jsonObject1.getString("my_pic");
                String email = jsonObject1.getString("email");

                arr.add(name);
            }


            adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>
                    (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arr);
            autoCompleteText.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
            autoCompleteText.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
            autoCompleteText.setTextColor(Color.RED);


        }
```

I hope this will work for you. Best of luck