# AutoCompleteTextView selecting words which starts with the letter typed

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I am using AutoCompleteTextView. Here I want to show only the names begin with the letter typed as currently it is showing all the words that contain this letter which I type.

```
fi_nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        fi_nameArray = mDbHelper.getFIName(a,m);

        ArrayAdapter<String> fi_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fi_nameArray);
        fiName.setThreshold(1);
        fiName.setAdapter(fi_adapter);

        fiName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ma_fiName = fiName.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

Comment: post your query from mDbHelper..

Comment: you need to implement custom filter on `ArrayAdapter`. have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
  fiName.setAdapter(fi_adapter);
     fiName.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: I am gettin error and app stopped if i include this showDropDown(). Do i want to write any method for it