# Customized autosuggestion view in android

Tags: android, autosuggest

I want to create a country-input-box with auto suggestion list.

The suggestion view will contain two list-box. one will contain all the countries which contain the partial word user typed. and next select list will contain name of all the continents based on the countries in the country-list.

User can click the country-list to choose a country or he can click to the continent to filter the item in the country list.

I want to know whether there is any way to accomplish it in android.

[image: example image]

NB: The above question is simplified to demo my requirement.

Comment: what do you have problem with?

Comment: @pskink I know to display a single list (here country list) as suggestion list. But I don't have any idea to display two lists and a label in suggestion-view.

Comment: you cannot have two dropdown lists, but you can combine countries and continents in one dropdown

Comment: Probably Custom adapter will help you. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter. I guess you need to create divider in custom adapter.