# Overlap a view in android

Tags: android, overlay

The main layout have four widgets- one EditText and three TextView as given below.

[image]

I want to add suggestion-list view dynamically as given below:
[image]

How to do it?

Comment: For solving the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962064/customized-autosuggestion-view-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AutoCompleteTextView. Described in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html.

Probably Custom adapter will help you to make two suggestions lists. Take a look at this [Autocompletetextview with custom adapter and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter). I guess you need to create divider in custom adapter.

As described in comments. Just Make listview visible when you need to show suggestions. Or paste in eclipse and remove android:visibility="gone" attribute and you will see gray listview over textviews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/search"
        android:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_1"
        android:text="text2" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/search"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Read the attached question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962064/customized-autosuggestion-view-in-android

Comment: Another soultion is to create EditText with ListView. Place listview with divider and filtered suggestions under your edittext and make it visible when user typing smthing in EditText.

Comment: Then the three TextView widgets will go down. The list view should overlap the three TextView widgets. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: And what's the problem? You can do this with relative layout.

Comment: Can you add xml structure for that in the answer?

Comment: Useful suggestions, let me try to solve my issue using these suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a class already built into android which gives you think functionality.

It's called [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: That can display only one list. Here I want two list.

Comment: It's unfair to downvote both answers. Both are good suggestions to start what looks like a god awful interface

Comment: Suggestion should be added as comment to the question, not as answer. Answer should be the solution to the question.