# How to populate values when I try to enter values in EditText field in Android?

Tags: android

I've following requirement and Since I'm new to this Android stuff, I'm not able to figure it out.

I've two Edit text fields for a driverName and a vehicleNumber. But these values shouldn't be new i.e 
When I try to enter driverName in particular EditText field, I should get all the driverNames populated so that I can choose one them. Same for vehicleNumber too. 
For this I already have data of driverName and Vehicle Number But my problem is how to populate them while entering in fields ??? Any good answer will be appreciated :)
Thank You.

Comment: You should go with `AutoCompeteTextView`. Search on __Google__ you will find many solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should go [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) as What M D suggested. Example is

> ```
> public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
>      protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
>          super.onCreate(icicle);
>          setContentView(R.layout.countries);
>
>          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
>                  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
>          AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
>                  findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
>          textView.setAdapter(adapter);
>      }
>
>      private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
>          "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
>      };
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thank You for this and just it occurred to me that If I also want to filter on auto completed values i.e if I give "gium", will I get "Belgium" ?

Comment: You will have to create a custom adapter for this which implements Filterable, in the getFilter() method

Comment: I would be so grateful If you could provide me and good references for that, I'm in dilemma so

Comment: example for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter