# Autocomplete textview got crashed for devices vesion 5.0 above

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete textview in my app,it works fine all devices and device version.But,my application got crashed while try to start typing in the autotextview for the device version 5.0 the app got crashed.

I have used the custom autocomplete text view adapter class from the following codings

[Autocompletetextview with custom adapter and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter)

It shows the following Error in the logcat

6-24 12:01:26.688  12893-12893/com.app.ex D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-24 12:01:26.699  12893-12893/com.app.ex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.ex, PID: 12893
    java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -512
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:843)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:803)
            at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:14291)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14047)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14061)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14061)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15135)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14066)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14061)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15135)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14066)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14061)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14061)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14856)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3200)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15135)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2595)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14066)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14089)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:266)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:272)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:311)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2522)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1998)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the code you're using, especially the part which causes the crash. Also post a more complete logcat. That line isn't probably the one to focus on

Comment: area_auto_adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(Home_Activity.this, R.layout.searchtext, R.id.searchtext, area_name_array);
                    txt_area.setAdapter(area_auto_adapter);

Answer (score 0):

It shows negative error exception.
So please check the array size whether the array you passed has a greater than size 0 or the adapter which you set to the autocomplete may be null or empty.

Answer (score -1):

My below code works perfectly in lollipop, can you check it out

```
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VehicleVo>
            implements Filterable {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context,
                int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            resultList = new ArrayList<VehicleVo>();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public VehicleVo getItem(int position) {
            return resultList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            //your layout design code goes gere
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            private TextView sLocationName;

        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                        resultList.addAll(vehiclelist);
                    } else {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {

                    LogUtil.d("result String" + results.count);

                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;

        }
    }
```

Comment: hi,madhu  Thanks for your reply then your saying that there is a problem in my adapter class only,but it works fine for all devices except the version 5.0

Comment: no it will not work: in `publishResults` you are not using `results.values` at all, so how is it supposed to work? also, please post a **working code**: yours doesn't even compile