# Text box with suggestions

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, textview, autocompletetextview

I am currently using an **AutoCompleteTextView** with a list of terms that gives suggestions as a user is typing. However, I want to use a different string algorithm than simply checking if a string contains your search term, that compares how close two strings are (e.g. searching "chcken" should show "chicken").

I have produced a method that takes a string parameter - your search query - and returns a sorted array of strings in the database that match that query based on relevance. How do I let the **AutoCompleteTextView** use that array? I can't simply attach it to the adapter with every keystroke, because that doesn't change the inherent behavior of the **AutoCompleteTextView** for only showing elements inside the array that MATCH the string query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom filter in your adapter.

Example:

```
public class MyFilterableAdapter extends ListAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return (String) resultValue;
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredArray;
                filterResults.count = filteredArray.size();
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    //here you will need to update the array where you are controlling what shows in the list
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since you did not provided any code, I don't know what adapter you are using, but you will need to implement all the adapter method (getCount, getView, etc).

You can find more info in those questions:

[How to create custom BaseAdapter for AutoCompleteTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview)

[Autocompletetextview with custom adapter and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter)

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I now have a working custom adapter, but I'm still quite nooby with Android and each entry on my autocomplete drop down menu shows another copy of the search bar... probably because I inflated the whole fragment with view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, viewGroup, false). What am I supposed to be inflating here, and where should I set the text in getView?

Comment: EDIT: Fixed it all. Thanks again for helping me get started