# Android : SetDropDownViewResource incompatible with AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, styles, spinner, autocompletetextview

The DropDownViewResource is applied on a Spinner but not on a AutoCompleteTextView.

**This works :**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, usersHistory);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner userSpinner = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.country);
userSpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
```

**This does NOT work :**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, usersHistory);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

AutoCompleteTextView userAutoCompleteTextView = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.country);
userAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);
```

Does anyone know how I can set a "custom dropdown layout" to the an AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter

Comment: @akshay Thank you, but why on Android should we always reinvent the wheel... It's a simple drop down list with an unique TextView. Can't we do it without using a custom adapter?

Answer (score 1):

For **AutoCompleteTextView**'s, it's the dropdown view resourceId that you pass into the ArrayAdapter's constructor.

So instead of:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, usersHistory);
```

It should be:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, usersHistory);
```

(Although I use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.)