# Implementing dropdown suggestions for SearchView

Tags: android, arraylist, dropdown, searchview, search-suggestion

[image]

I have a SeachView object.

What I want to implement is what is presented from the picture here at the top.

I want to keep it simple and only load data from an Arraylist of Strings, not need for some fancy local storage fetching etc - leave that for me to deal with it later.

How can I add to my SearchView a dropdown suggestions as seen in the picture that is being filled with data from an Arraylist?

Comment: you could do it with autocompletetextview https://medium.com/@droidbyme/autocomplete-textview-in-android-a1bf5fc112f6

Comment: use autoCompleteTextView and implement Filterable. [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter][1]

Comment: How can I add the magnifying glass icon to autocompletetextview ?

Comment: plus, there are some functionalities of SearchViews that I need more - the "search" button in the keyboard, the "X" button in the edittext and the `setOnQueryTextListener` method. Is there a way to get the functionality that I need using SearchView?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add recycler view below your navigation bar.
Initially, the visibility of this recycler view will be GONE but when the user starts typing you can simply set its visibility to visible.