# How to appear recyclerview lists on top of views like spinner items?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have multiple edittext views, one in which the user will type some letters, and a search item list will appear using a text watcher. Currently, the list appearing after typing some letters takes space between edittexts, and other edittexts go down from their actual place. I want other edittexts to be at the same place when lists appear and lists appearing should appear on top of other fields like spinner items.
If you will see the image items appearing in the list should come on the top and all other edittexts shouldn't move from their place.
[image]

Comment: just use AutoCompleteTextView of Android

Comment: Are you trying to make something like this? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-search-an-item-in-listview-using-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/amp/

Comment: @KartikAgarwal Can I apply text watcher in autocomplete textview and make an api call to get lists only related to text observed as an input? If yes, then please explain also.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoCompleteTextView, yes you can also hit an API to fetch data.
You can get more information from here:
[Autocomplete Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782288/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-and-filter)